# How to run a JUnit test case for Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit

I am taking an online Android course. My assignment is to run the three JUnit test cases provided. The instructions simply say to run the code as a JUnit test case in Eclipse. I do not know what I am doing wrong but I end up with this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

This might sound noobish but, what is the right way of executing the test cases?

Comment: Sounds like the class file for `android/test/ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` has not been generated yet, or is not in the classpath.  Try building your project and then searching from the project root directory for `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.class`.  If you're using an IDE it should tell you where it is putting generated class files and you can look in there directly.

Comment: Also see [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html) with information for running tests from the command line.